# How to store URLs inside a string in java

Tags: java, json

I've been trying to parse a particular section of a json object. To be more specific, i'm fetching http://www.dprobuk.com/api/get_post?id=677&include=title,id,content which is a JSON array, and in that i've extracted the "content" key. So the real problem for me is now inside the content key, there is a textarea tag whose content i want to store it inside the string. But while doing so i am getting illegal escape sequence error.

Example:
String st="http:\/\/www.dprobuk.com/" so its naturally illegal, is there some other way in java to store the above string? or some other way to split textarea from the above JSON Array ?

[image: This is the json array which i am trying]

```
<div id="my"></div><script>
var st="<textarea wrap=\"soft\" class=\"crayon-plain print-no\" data-settings=\"dblclick\" readonly style=\"-moz-tab-size:4; -o-tab-size:4; -webkit-tab-size:4; tab-size:4; font-size: 12px !important; line-height: 15px !important;\">"+
"\n&lt;html&gt;\r\n    &lt;head&gt;\r\n        &lt;title&gt;HTML Form using Bootstrap&lt;\/title&gt;\r\n        &lt;meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"&gt; \r\n        &lt;link href=\"https:\/\/maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com\/bootstrap\/3.3.5\/css\/bootstrap.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"&gt;\r\n        &lt;script src=\"https:\/\/maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com\/bootstrap\/3.3.5\/js\/bootstrap.min.js\" type=\"text\/javascript\"&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;\r\n    &lt;\/head&gt;\r\n    &lt;body style=\"background:url(pattern1.jpg);\"&gt;    \r\n        &lt;div class=\"container\"&gt;\r\n            &lt;div class=\"row\"&gt;\r\n                &lt;div class=\"col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2\"&gt;\r\n                    &lt;h1&gt;This is a Sample Form Using BootStrap&lt;\/h1&gt;\r\n                    &lt;br\/&gt;&lt;br\/&gt;\r\n                    &lt;form name=\"sentMessage\" id=\"contactForm\" novalidate&gt;\r\n                        &lt;div class=\"row control-group\"&gt;\r\n                            &lt;div class=\"form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls\"&gt;\r\n                                &lt;label&gt;Name&lt;\/label&gt;\r\n                                &lt;input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Name\" id=\"name\" required data-validation-required-message=\"Please enter your name.\"&gt;\r\n                                &lt;p class=\"help-block text-danger\"&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n                            &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n                        &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n                        &lt;div class=\"row control-group\"&gt;\r\n                            &lt;div class=\"form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls\"&gt;\r\n                                &lt;label&gt;Email Address&lt;\/label&gt;\r\n                                &lt;input type=\"email\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Email Address\" id=\"email\" required data-validation-required-message=\"Please enter your email address.\"&gt;\r\n                                &lt;p class=\"help-block text-danger\"&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n                            &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n                        &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n                        &lt;div class=\"row control-group\"&gt;\r\n                            &lt;div class=\"form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls\"&gt;\r\n                                &lt;label&gt;Phone Number&lt;\/label&gt;\r\n                                &lt;input type=\"tel\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Phone Number\" id=\"phone\" required data-validation-required-message=\"Please enter your phone number.\"&gt;\r\n                                &lt;p class=\"help-block text-danger\"&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n                            &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n                        &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n                        &lt;div class=\"row control-group\"&gt;\r\n                            &lt;div class=\"form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls\"&gt;\r\n                                &lt;label&gt;Message&lt;\/label&gt;\r\n                                &lt;textarea rows=\"5\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Message\" id=\"message\" required data-validation-required-message=\"Please enter a message.\"&gt;&lt;\/textarea&gt;\r\n                                &lt;p class=\"help-block text-danger\"&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n                            &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n                        &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n                        &lt;br&gt;\r\n                        &lt;div class=\"row\"&gt;\r\n                            &lt;div class=\"form-group col-xs-12\"&gt;\r\n                                &lt;button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-lg\"&gt;Send&lt;\/button&gt;\r\n                            &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n                        &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n                    &lt;\/form&gt;\r\n                &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n            &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n        &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n    &lt;\/body&gt;\r\n&lt;\/html&gt;"+
"<\/textarea>";
var ta = document.getElementById('my');
ta.innerHTML=st;</script>
```

The Above code works but when i use the same variable st as a string in Java, it fails to compile !

```
class SimpleCode
{
public static void main(String []as)
{
    String st="<textarea wrap=\"soft\" class=\"crayon-plain print-no\" data-settings=\"dblclick\" readonly style=\"-moz-tab-size:4; -o-tab-size:4; -webkit-tab-size:4; tab-size:4; font-size: 12px !important; line-height: 15px !important;\">"+
    "\n&lt;html&gt;\r\n    &lt;head&gt;\r\n        &lt;title&gt;HTML Form using Bootstrap&lt;\/title&gt;\r\n        &lt;meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"&gt; \r\n        &lt;link href=\"https:\/\/maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com\/bootstrap\/3.3.5\/css\/bootstrap.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"&gt;\r\n        &lt;script src=\"https:\/\/maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com\/bootstrap\/3.3.5\/js\/bootstrap.min.js\" type=\"text\/javascript\"&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;\r\n    &lt;\/head&gt;\r\n    &lt;body style=\"background:url(pattern1.jpg);\"&gt;    \r\n        &lt;div class=\"container\"&gt;\r\n            &lt;div class=\"row\"&gt;\r\n                &lt;div class=\"col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2\"&gt;\r\n                    &lt;h1&gt;This is a Sample Form Using BootStrap&lt;\/h1&gt;\r\n                    &lt;br\/&gt;&lt;br\/&gt;\r\n                    &lt;form name=\"sentMessage\" id=\"contactForm\" novalidate&gt;\r\n                        &lt;div class=\"row control-group\"&gt;\r\n                            &lt;div class=\"form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls\"&gt;\r\n                                &lt;label&gt;Name&lt;\/label&gt;\r\n                                &lt;input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Name\" id=\"name\" required data-validation-required-message=\"Please enter your name.\"&gt;\r\n                                &lt;p class=\"help-block text-danger\"&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n                            &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n                        &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n                        &lt;div class=\"row control-group\"&gt;\r\n                            &lt;div class=\"form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls\"&gt;\r\n                                &lt;label&gt;Email Address&lt;\/label&gt;\r\n                                &lt;input type=\"email\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Email Address\" id=\"email\" required data-validation-required-message=\"Please enter your email address.\"&gt;\r\n                                &lt;p class=\"help-block text-danger\"&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n                            &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n                        &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n                        &lt;div class=\"row control-group\"&gt;\r\n                            &lt;div class=\"form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls\"&gt;\r\n                                &lt;label&gt;Phone Number&lt;\/label&gt;\r\n                                &lt;input type=\"tel\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Phone Number\" id=\"phone\" required data-validation-required-message=\"Please enter your phone number.\"&gt;\r\n                                &lt;p class=\"help-block text-danger\"&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n                            &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n                        &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n                        &lt;div class=\"row control-group\"&gt;\r\n                            &lt;div class=\"form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls\"&gt;\r\n                                &lt;label&gt;Message&lt;\/label&gt;\r\n                                &lt;textarea rows=\"5\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Message\" id=\"message\" required data-validation-required-message=\"Please enter a message.\"&gt;&lt;\/textarea&gt;\r\n                                &lt;p class=\"help-block text-danger\"&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n                            &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n                        &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n                        &lt;br&gt;\r\n                        &lt;div class=\"row\"&gt;\r\n                            &lt;div class=\"form-group col-xs-12\"&gt;\r\n                                &lt;button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-lg\"&gt;Send&lt;\/button&gt;\r\n                            &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n                        &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n                    &lt;\/form&gt;\r\n                &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n            &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n        &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n    &lt;\/body&gt;\r\n&lt;\/html&gt;"+
    "<\/textarea>";
    System.out.println(st);
}
}
```

So all i want to know about any other procedure to make it work ?

Comment: can you share your code? How are you parsing the JSON array?

Comment: You can try to url encode and url decode thoses Strings.
http://www.url-encode-decode.com/
In java, you have the URLEncoder clss
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: updated the question with code used !

Answer (score 1):

```
private class AsyncDataClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection .setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection .setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnection .setConnectTimeout(1000 * 6);
                httpURLConnection .setReadTimeout(1000 * 6);

                //InputStream to get response
                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection .getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(IS, "iso-8859-1"));
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                String json;
                while( (json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    response.append(json + "\n");
                    break;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                IS.close();
                httpURLConnection .disconnect();
                return response.toString().trim();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            System.out.println("Resulted Value: " + result);
            if(result.equals("") || result == null){
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            int jsonResult = returnParsedJsonObject(result);

            if(jsonResult == 1){
                //PARSE DATA here;
            }
        }
    }

    private int returnParsedJsonObject(String result){
        JSONObject resultObject = null;
        int returnedResult = 0;
        try {
            resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
            if ( resultObject.length() > 0 ){
returnedResult = 1;
} else {
returnedResult = 0;

}
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return returnedResult;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this is not my issue. I've updated my question with what i needed to approach . Thanks :)